# How To Perfectly Center Three Columns In Opera And Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

I have Three columns between Two Sidebars (Centered and responsive) in my page. It looks good in all browsers except Opera and Safari. *It is **not** centered in those two browsers.*

It looks like this in Firefox,Chrome and IE:

http://www.vasinternetposao.com/center_problem/center.png

This is how it looks in Opera and Safari:

http://www.vasinternetposao.com/center_problem/not_centered_opera.png

This is my CSS:

```
#blogs_three_cols .left_column {
width: 32.7%;
}

#blogs_three_cols .middle_column {
margin-left: 0.95%;
width: 32.7%;
margin-right: 0.95%;
}

#blogs_three_cols .right_column {
margin:0;
width: 32.7%;       
}
```

Here is the **[Live Page](http://www.vasinternetposao.com/wordpressdevelopment/)** (Try to toggle between pages "Three Columns" and "Sample page" to see the difference).

My question is: How can I center my columns **perfectly** in all browsers without using nasty CSS hacks for Opera and Safari? Can it be done?

Thank you Stackers!

Answer (score 1):

Your container div#blogs_three_cols is not centered.add a
margin:0 auto
to the container and omit 
float:left
from it.

Comment: Different browsers have small differences in rendering html and css. some of these problems may be solved by using html and css design rules truly and some does not solve even by using rules truly in cases like this you can change css class on page load with jquery.

Comment: Yeah I know that and I also know that I can "fix" that by using browser specific hacks for Opera and Safari but I don't want to do that...

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has a clear CSS solution or better Jquery/Javascript for this i would like to hear it:=) Anyway i will change classes based on browser detection like this:

```
j(document).ready(function() {
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
//Opera check and safari...
if (window.opera && window.opera.buildNumber || isSafari ) { 
//add some classes for Opera and Safari browsers...
}
}
```